# Translate Model's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, translation

What's the best way to handle the following problem with rails 3.0.3?

I have a Model(id, name) Nationality, in which I store different nationalities

ie: French, German, Belgian

My application should be available in multiples languages, so the select input which contains the nationalities should show French, German, Belgian if the locale is set to english, and should show Francais, Allemand, Belge if the locale is set to french.

Where to store the translation and how to use them in my code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create the following structure in your en.yml:

```
#en.yml
en:
  label_french: French
  label_german: German
```

Then you can call the following from your views:

```
<%= t("label_#{@nationality.name}") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the puret gem which hooks into your existing schema without changing it.
https://github.com/jo/puret#readme

Answer (score 0):

All is explain on i18n rails guides : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: thks for your answer, that's where I was looking, it is explained how to translate the Model'name or Model's attributes, but not how to translate the values of the model.